# Row Widget use entire column

Tags: android, flutter

Try to build a custom button with X sign on the right, but when I add this to a Wrap widget, it used up the entire row.

this is the code for building the button:

```dart
Material _buildDeleteFilter(String caption, Function onTap) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.orange,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onTap,
        splashColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 5),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                caption,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.close,
                size: 20,
                color: Colors.white,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Try changing `MainAxisSize` of `Row` to the minimum. See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MainAxisSize-class.html

Comment: Ah, missed that part, thank you.